# How do I create a custom AlertDialog that will be able to pass inputted data back to the calling Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my application, I want the user to be able to do 3 things:

1. Open a dialog.
2. Allow the user to input two strings within that dialog.
3. Click an "Okay" button, and have the two strings passed back to the calling activity.

I am trying to follow the example [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#java), but it's not going well.

This is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Some Text Here"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/my_custom_style"
            android:text="From: "
            android:labelFor="@+id/from"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/from"
            style="@style/my_custom_style"
            android:inputType="date"/>

        <TextView
            style="@style/my_custom_style"
            android:text="To: "
            android:labelFor="@+id/to"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/to"
            style="@style/my_custom_style"
            android:inputType="date"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel"/>

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/button_okay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/okay"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my class that extends `DialogFragment`:

```
public class MyCustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_layout, null));
        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }

}
```

Now, in my calling activity I am trying to do this:

```
MyCustomDialogFragment myCustomDialogFragment = new MyCustomDialogFragment();

// Since the onCreate() method of my custom DialogFragment returns an android.app.Dialog, I thought I could do this:

Dialog dialog = new CustomDialogFragment();
```

Of course, this did work, I get the:

```
Incompatible types.

    Required: android.app.Dialog

    Found: com.me.MyCustomDialogFragment
```

error, even though the `onCreate()` method does return `android.app.Dialog`. I cannot even cast it to `Dialog`. So, how can I accomplish my 3 goals from above?

There are "a lot" of examples out there, but they are all just variations on the default Google example, which is not very thorough.

Comment: Simply call myCustomDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager) without casting it to Dialog

Comment: Looks like myCustomDialogFragment.onGetDialog() is what gets the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I accomplish my 3 goals from above?
>
> 1. Open a dialog.

Call `show()` on your `MyCustomDialogFragment` instance, passing in a `FragmentManager`. While [the framework `DialogFragment` is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), its JavaDocs show how to use `show()`.

> 2. Allow the user to input two strings within that dialog.

Your layout seems to offer this, though you will want to get rid of your buttons, since `AlertDialog` provides those.

> 3. Click an "Okay" button, and have the two strings passed back to the calling activity.

[Call `setPositiveButton()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html?hl=en#setPositiveButton(int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)) on your `AlertDialog.Builder`. Have the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` that you pass into `setPositiveButton()` get the values out of your `EditText` widgets and get that data to your activity (e.g., use a shared `ViewModel` between this fragment and the activity, and have the fragment update `LiveData` in the `ViewModel` with the `EditText` contents).

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Dialogs/DialogFragment) shows the basics of using `DialogFragment`, albeit using the since-deprecated framework `DialogFragment` implementation and not using `ViewModel`.